# PHP file which is opened by AJAX - Give Captcha alert and send url-data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation, captcha

Sitting on this already the whole day, if you believe or not :)
I want to transfer data via GET-Method to an external .jsp file (example.com/data.php?attribute=value&a2=v2 and so on)

This all seems to work so far and also the validation. Now I have the problem that I have a captcha which is generated by a php-file and the captcha is controlled/validated in the PHP-File where the HTML-Form data is posted to.

When everything is OK I can do a alert in the submitHandler (success: function(response)) but how can I get an alert now, if the Captcha is incorrect?

How can I solve this? Can I get a value oder variable throught AJAX back from the PHP File to do something with it (to display the alert)?

Would be very glad for any help or comments.

Thank you!

**HERE** the data is validated and sent to PHP file after successful validation.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};
    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            $("#form-id").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    .........
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    ..........
                },
                submitHandler: function(form)
                    var data = $("#nachricht").serializeArray();
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"nachricht.php",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(response) {
                    alert('Thank you!');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

**THE PHP FILE:**
Here the data is transferred to another URL (GET-Method) and the Captcha is checked

```
$email = urlencode($_POST['email']);
$name = urlencode($_POST["name"]);
....

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['captcha_spam']) AND $_POST["captchafield"] == $_SESSION['captcha_spam']) // Captcha korrekt
{
    unset($_SESSION['captcha_spam']);

$link = "http://www.example.com/data.jsp?email=" . $email . "&name=" . $name . $titel . "&text=" . $text . "&ranking=" . $ranking . "&captchafield=" . $captcha_s;

header( "refresh:0;url=" . $link);
exit;
....
```

Comment: Why do you make a refresh in the php?

Comment: Do you mean the header()? This I use to send the data with via GET to an jsp-file on an other server..

Comment: Yes. I do. Why is it needed?

Comment: For the data transfer to an other server. First I wanted to use cURL but I don't have any access to the Server with the jsp-file and wouldn't be able to get any bug report if it is not working. So now I transfer the data via AJAX to the PHP file and manually open the URL with the GET-variables on it. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: And what does it do in this context? This will redirect the ajax request to the jsp file?

Comment: No the AJAX-request should not be redirected, it is just there so that the form data is processed (and sent to the jsp file) without the user leaving the page. And in the PHP file the captcha is validated, so I need some idea how to get the information back, if the captcha is not entered correctly.

Comment: Then just echo something.
I mean if( ... captcha ok ... ) then echo "Success"; else echo "Failed"; And check the response parameter in success action.

Comment: I already have an if-condition on that but the problem is, that this is not displayed.  $_POST["captchafield"] == $_SESSION['captcha_spam']) Captcha korrekt
{ ... correct } else { echo fail .. }

Comment: You have to handle it on javascript side.

Comment: So you mean between validating all fields and sending AJAX request there should be the Captcha validation? How can I include this in javascript? With another AJAX-request?

Comment: No no you misunderstood me. Can you paste pls all of your php? or if its long then only the captcha check's statement and the else

Comment: In the PHP file which is opened after form submit is only the PHP content from above and then  ..  echo "..success.."; } else { echo "...fail.."; }. In the captcha-PHP-File there is created a session and the captcha string. Or what do you mean? Thanks for the help

Comment: If php works well, and checks captcha, and goes also to the jsp file, and run it, then you dont have to touch it. In javascript you have a `success: function( response )` the response is what came from php, so for example ...success... you can check this. and alert message by `response` 's value

Comment: OK, so when I do in the PHP-file like: if(enteredcaptcha == captcha){ $captcha_correct = true; } else { $captcha_correct = false; } how can I check this in the response and execute an alert() ?

Comment: This no way. But if you do echo "captcha_correct"; if success, then you can check it in javascript by this way: if( response == "captcha_correct" ) alert("Success"); else { alert("unsuccess.."); }

Answer (score 0):

OK so now I have in my PHP file where the form is submitted to:

```
if(enteredcaptcha == captcha){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('captcha_correct');</script>";  
} else { 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('captcha_not_correct');</script>";  
}
```

and in my normal HTML file where the Form and Javascript is I have:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
                    var data = $("#kommentar").serializeArray();
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"kommentar.php",
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(response) {
                    if( response == "captcha_is_correct" ){ alert("Success"); } else { alert("unsuccess.."); }
                        }
                    });

                }
```

And this makes really sense, wonderful, but I'm always getting the message "unsucces", so I think there is still a bug somehow?